# Retrieve N:N Relationship in Dynamics Crm

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2013

Currency entity is associated N:N Relationship with Lead.Now I'm trying to Retrieve associated Currency with the lead.i'm getting problem transaction currency does'nt contain attribute with leadid.could any references plz...

```c#
if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && (context.InputParameters["Target"]) is Entity)
{
    Entity en = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
    QueryExpression _Query = new QueryExpression
    {
        EntityName = "transactioncurrency",
        ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true),
        LinkEntities = 
        { 
            new LinkEntity 
            { 
                Columns=new ColumnSet(true),
                LinkFromEntityName="lead",
                LinkFromAttributeName="leadid",
                LinkToEntityName="new_lead_transactioncurrency",
                LinkToAttributeName="transactioncurrencyid",
                LinkCriteria=new FilterExpression  
                {
                    FilterOperator=LogicalOperator.And,
                    Conditions=
                    { 
                        new ConditionExpression  
                        {
                            AttributeName="transactioncurrencyid",
                            Operator=ConditionOperator.Equal,
                            Values={ en.Id }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    EntityCollection entitycollect = service.RetrieveMultiple(_Query);
    int entitycount = entitycollect.Entities.Count;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to identify the correct `LinkFromAttributeName` and `LinkToAttributeName`.

```C#
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression(entity1);

query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);

LinkEntity linkEntity1 = new LinkEntity("lead", "new_lead_transactioncurrency", "leadid", "leadid", JoinOperator.Inner);

LinkEntity linkEntity2 = new LinkEntity("new_lead_transactioncurrency", "transactioncurrency", "transactioncurrencyid", "transactioncurrencyid", JoinOperator.Inner);

linkEntity1.LinkEntities.Add(linkEntity2);
query.LinkEntities.Add(linkEntity1);

// Add condition to match the Bike name with “Honda”
linkEntity2.LinkCriteria = new FilterExpression();

linkEntity2.LinkCriteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("raj_bikename", ConditionOperator.Equal, "Honda"));

EntityCollection collRecords = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

For reference please have a look at the followng links:

[Retrieve associated records (N:N related)](http://rajeevpentyala.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/retrieve-associated-records-nn-related/)

[Sample: Convert queries between Fetch and QueryExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547457.aspx)

Comment: yes. i saw that blog in link entity there is no parameter relationshipentityname.it will have only from/to entitynames,attribute names.could you plz help me out.

Comment: `relationshipentityname` is just a place holder. Please find relationship name under Settings > Customization > Customize The System > Entities (Under Component). Then expand the entity you are working on. Relationship name will be under `N:N Relationships`.

Comment: Yes. i know the relationship names but there is no parameter in link entity.could you clarify the query.

Comment: i'm getting this error.Additional information: 'TransactionCurrency' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name = 'leadid'.

Comment: YOu need to idenfity the right `LinkFromAttributeName` and `LinkToAttributeName`. go through all the lookup fields on TransactionCurrency. Check which one represents leads.

Comment: i checked in transactioncurrency it has n:n relationship name=lead_transectioncurrencyid and it does'nt contain any id.

Comment: transaction currency has n:n relationshipname new_lead_transactioncurrency.it does contain any attribute or id

Comment: could you plz clarify me

Comment: If you carefully read the first link. It clearly says that  If you create N:N relationship between 2 entities, it creates an intermediate entity (i.e. Relationship Entity) with 3 fields (High lighted in screenshot). To find this go to Settings > Customization > Customize The System > Entities (Under Component). Then expand the entity you are working on. Relationship name will be under N:N Relationships. Double click on the relationship you are working on. Check what you got in `Relationship Entity Name`

Comment: i tried as it was in blog.LinkEntity linkEntity1 = new LinkEntity("lead", "new_lead_transactioncurrency", "leadid", "lead", JoinOperator.Inner);
                LinkEntity linkEntity2 = new LinkEntity("new_lead_transactioncurrency", "transactioncurrency", "transactioncurrencyid", "transactioncurrency", JoinOperator.Inner);getting error at transactioncurrency does contain lead attribute. i gone thru transactioncuurency entity there is no field attributes related to lead only n:n relationship it has where i'm getting wrong clarify me

Comment: getting error at transactioncurrency does contain lead attribute. i gone thru transactioncuurency entity there is no field attributes related to lead only n:n relationship it has where i'm getting wrong clarify me

Comment: `lead` is an entity name. It can't be the primary field of Entity 1.

Comment: just a guess. Try to replace value of 4th parameter with `transactioncurrencyid`.

Comment: i changed 4th parameter to transactioncurrencyid.its getting error at transactioncurrency doesn't contain attribute with name=leadid

Comment: relationship entity always contain 4 columns. ie. 1) First Entities Primiry Field. 2) Second Entities Primary Field. 3) Relationship entity Id. 4) VersionNumber.

Comment: then where i'm doing wrong.clarify me.from yesterday onwards i'm trying to resolve this one

Comment: TBH, I not on top of my head.

Comment: Try this once:             LinkEntity linkEntity1 = new LinkEntity("lead", "new_lead_transactioncurrency", "leadid", "leadid", JoinOperator.Inner);

            LinkEntity linkEntity2 = new LinkEntity("new_lead_transactioncurrency", "transactioncurrency", "transactioncurrencyid", "transactioncurrencyid", JoinOperator.Inner);

Comment: its getting same error at transactioncurrency doesn't contain attribute with name=leadid

Comment: Please let me know if it sorted and what was the exact issue.

Comment: finally i got it man.using addlink method in query expression

Comment: Well done. Can you share you code please. You can answer your own question to close the question, if you think you have the solution.

Comment: Sure.Using AddLink Method Like this   qx.AddLink("new_lead_transactioncurrency", "transactioncurrencyid", "transactioncurrencyid");